# How to terminate infinite scrolling using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on this javascript based slider
I want the slider to hide the next button when it reaches the final slide and should not slide after that
how can I do this

[Codepen Link](https://codpen.io/qyOP6)

Comment: Infinite scroll does not have final slide... That's why it's infinite. Basically you check if you have next element. If no - hide next button

Comment: @Justinas could you suggest how can i do it in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it for you sorry

```
function shiftSlide(dir, action) {
    items.classList.add('shifting');
     items.classList.add('shifting');
    console.log(index)
    if (allowShift) {
      if (!action) { posInitial = items.offsetLeft; }

      if (dir == 1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial - slideSize) + "px";
        index += dir;      
      } else if (dir == -1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial + slideSize) + "px";
        index+= dir;      
      }
      if(index == slidesLength -1){
           document.querySelector('#next').style.display = 'none';
          document.querySelector('#prev').style.display = 'block';
      }
    else if(index == 0){
       document.querySelector('#prev').style.display = 'none';
       document.querySelector('#next').style.display = 'block';
    }
      else{
        document.querySelector('#prev').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('#next').style.display = 'block';
      }
    };

    allowShift = false;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i block sliding after it reaches to final slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can check when you shift the image if it is the last elm in the list and make the button display none

```js
  function shiftSlide(dir, action) {
    items.classList.add('shifting');
    if(index == document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide').length){
         document.querySelector('#next').style.display = 'none';
}
    if (allowShift) {
      if (!action) { posInitial = items.offsetLeft; }

      if (dir == 1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial - slideSize) + "px";
        index++;      
      } else if (dir == -1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial + slideSize) + "px";
        index--;      
      }
    };

    allowShift = false;
  }
```

Comment: it's not working at all. did you applied it in given link?